# Code Rally Login Error

Tags: code-rally

I am getting an error saying I am not logged in to the server when attempting to submit my vehicle to the http://challenge-na.coderallycloud.com contest server.  When I bring up the server list it shows that I am Online and logged in using my userid.

When I test the connection it is successful.

Unable to submit vehicle (after 10-15 minutes)
Unable to enter ChrisHanksCarOne on NA Contest Service

You need to login to the server before continuing to race.  In the Code Rally Developer View choose the server list, right-click on the server and click login.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What do I do to fix this?

Comment: Interesting, I can't seem to log in to the server at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633572/code-rally-login-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the OAuth login hasn't worked properly, and the Eclipse plugin hasn't detected that. To fix log out from the server and login again (you can do this from the servers window or through the bottom of the enter race window). You should be asked to authenticate with Google, Facebook or Twitter - use the account you registered with on InfoQ and it should work (if not let me know and I can look into it further).

Comment: Hi Thomas.  I have rebooted several times and when I pull down the server list it normally says I am already logged in to the server.  I logout. Then when I try to login the [Server Username] window just hangs for Server: NA Contest Server.  If I close the window, change servers and come back it says I am logged in.  There are no windows for logging in through Gmail at any time.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit.code rally 1.4.0.0

Comment: Hi Christopher - can you confirm that when you click "login" it then asks you for a username, and when you enter one and click "login" on that window that the window closes and you get a "you are now logged in" message? No login prompt at all? Also when did you install code rally, and did you have an older version (before 28th June 2015) installed before?

Comment: I only installed the product once

Comment: When I click login it pops the "Server Username" window that asks for my 'Username:'.  I type in my user name and press login and the box hangs (no response).  After a while if I close the box and swap servers (to IBM Cloud for instance) and swap back to the NA Contest Server it shows that I am logged in as my user id.  No other messages appear regarding login.

Comment: It worked the first couple of days.  Could installing a localhost server so that I could get output from my program have caused the problem with the login process?

Comment: Hi Chris. Installing a local server will not have caused an issue with login, although you do need to make sure that if you run more than one local server that they are using different ports to each other (you change ports for local servers in the server.xml file for a server).

If you don't get prompted for logging in via google, facebook or twitter it sounds like a local browser issue. Can you make sure that Eclipse is set to use the in-built browser, and if that doesn't work clear cookies for the browser eclipse is set to use in your system then login again.