# Code Rally Login Not Working

Tags: code-rally

For starters, I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

When I try to connect my username to the server and it asks for logging in with social network, I am unable to do so.

For "Login With Facebook", the page ends up going to facebook and a pop up displays saying:

```
App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't 
have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app 
admin for permissions.
```

So, I guessed the facebook app wasn't set up properly and created a new user using Twitter. But logging in with Twitter fails as well. The OAuth goes through but when coming back to the app it says:

```
 We were not able to match your social media account with this 
 username. Ensure your username is correct or the social media login 
 method is correct. Please close the browser and try again.
```

The link for "Or visit the Code Rally community for more details!" doesn't work either and I can't comment on any of the blog posts.

I am running out of social network logins so please advise what to do. Also, one thing to note is when I signup, I signup with a different email than the social network one, would that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

which server are you trying to login on? (NA/EU/BR/IN/CN etc).

I'll go check the Facebook setup now to make sure I've not missed something, however it will help me narrow down the issue if I know which server is having issues.

The reason you can't login with Twitter on your ID is that it will already be associated with your Facebook ID which you registered with on InfoQ's contest site. To use Twitter you'll need to re-register a new ID on InfoQ's site and link it to your Twitter account (although I'd prefer to fix whatever is messing with the Facebook login).

**edit**

Looks like there was an issue in our Facebook OAuth config - it should be fixed now :-)

Comment: I am trying to log in to NA, the Facebook OAuth is fixed but now I keep getting the "We were not able to match your social media account with this 
 username." error. Also, I was getting that error through the Twitter account after making a new username on InfoQ. Again, I do remember changing the email after connecting the social accounts on the InfoQ registration.

Comment: Each username gets linked to a social media account when it is first created on InfoQ's page or logged into via the game UI. Once that connection is made it is the only way to login to that username.

If you're having issues with a current username I'm afraid the fastest fix (other than trying with different combinations of your login) would be to go back to InfoQ's webpage and create a new registration with a new username/social media login combo and to use that. We don't restrict people from having the same oauth linked to multiple usernames so it should not be a problem.

Comment: If you still have issues with a new username/OAuth login please post which username you're trying to login with to see if we had errors when you created the account.